# Get the value of last record of every month (Django)

Tags: mysql, django, django-queryset

My Model:

```
class Transaction (models.Model):
    transaction_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    net_monthly_transaction = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2, default=0)
    # deposit or withdrawal (withdrawal with negative value)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2)
    time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return str(self.time_stamp)  + str(self.amount) + str(self.net_monthly_transaction)
```

My aim is to get the value of net_monthly_transaction from the last entry in every month.

With help of S.O. I have managed to get this far:

```
truncate_date = connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('month', 'time_stamp')
        lem = Transaction.objects.extra({'month':truncate_date}).values('month').annotate(last_record=Max('time_stamp')).values_list('net_monthly_transaction', flat=True)
```

The above query is suppose to get the value of net_monthly_transaction from the max time_stamp in every month.

But it doesn't.

If I create three entries for October one after the other:

1. net_monthly_transaction = 3000
2. net_monthly_transaction = 4000
3. net_monthly_transaction = 5000

all 3 values will be returned by the query.

In the other hand:

1. net_monthly_transaction = 3000
2. net_monthly_transaction = 2000
3. net_monthly_transaction = 1000

Then only the value 3000 is returned.

So there is a condition set somewhere based on the size of the net_monthly_transaction. I am bit lost as to how I can solve this.

Can someone please provide some direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Django are you using? The answer is different depending on that

Comment: @TitusP I am using the latest django and latest python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd solve this by using two querysets (unless the simpler approach below is an option). As long as you don't explicitly evaluate `last_entries` this will result in a single query when you evaluate `transactions`.

```
from django.db.models import Max
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth

# Selects last time_stamp for each month
last_entries = (Transaction.objects
    .annotate(tx_month=TruncMonth('time_stamp'))
    .values('tx_month')
    .annotate(last_entry=Max('time_stamp'))
    .values_list('last_entry', flat=True))

# Selects transactions with time_stamps matching last_entries
# ie. last transaction in each month
transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(
    time_stamp__in=last_entries
)
```

`transactions` is a normal queryset containing the last Transaction instance in each month. If you want a simple list of `net_monthly_transaction` values with no other information you can add:

```
net_values = transactions.values_list(
    'net_monthly_transaction', flat=True
)
```

One thing to be really careful about is that if two entries have identical time stamps then both of them will appear in the result set.

### A simpler approach

If `net_monthly_transaction` is simply the sum of all `amount`s for a given month, then you can use something like this instead of the above

```
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth

transactions = (Transaction.objects
    .annotate(month=TruncMonth('time_stamp'))
    .values('month')
    .annotate(month_net=Sum('amount')))
```

Now `transactions` contains dicts representing the last transaction for each month. Each dict has a `month` key containing the month and a`month_net` key which contains the month's net transactions. As a bonus, you don't have to worry about entries with identical time stamps.

Of course, if `net_monthly_transaction` is the result of a more complex calculation then this might not be an option.

### Your initial approach

Your initial query isn't working for two main reasons.

1. This kind of query usually relies either on joining the table to itself or on a subquery in the WHERE clause. I don't know of a good way to do either of those with a single queryset using Django's ORM unless you resort to stuffing raw SQL in `extra()` or something along those lines. But producing a WHERE clause subquery is trivial if you use two querysets the way we did above.
2. It doesn't make sense to use `values_list()` in this way

   ```
   truncate_date = connection.ops.date_trunc_sql('month', 'time_stamp')
   lem = Transaction.objects.extra({'month':truncate_date}).values('month').annotate(last_record=Max('time_stamp'))
   ```

   Up to this point it's similar to the `last_entries` queryset used above. We're selecting unique month values and the last time_stamp for each one of those months.

   When we add `.values_list('net_monthly_transaction', flat=True)` we're telling the query builder that we only care about the `net_monthly_transaction` field, so it throws away everything else and produces something like this

   ```
   SELECT "transaction"."net_monthly_transaction"
   FROM "transaction"
   GROUP BY "transaction"."net_monthly_transaction"
   ```

   The `GROUP BY` is the only thing left from the `extra` and `annotate` calls, and even that has been changed so that it doesn't do what we wanted it to do.

Comment: Your simpler approach works, and I can safely delete the "net_monthly_transaction" field. This is perfect so far. And your explanation helps a lot in understanding, thanks Kevin.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the last record of the month, first filter all the records of that month and then order them in ascending order and select the last record which should be the latest record. The below query should work in this order.

```
Transaction.objects.filter(time_stamp__month=month_you_are_checking).order_by('time_stamp').last()
```

P.S. Not tested.

Comment: I'm not talking about one month, I'm talking about every month. That is why truncation is needed, but after that it gets a bit murky in Django.